# How to display error in different controller after post in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, modelstate

First thing, sorry for my English.

I have two forms in index.

Login form will post to localhost/Account/LogOn

Register form will post to localhost/Account/SignUp

How can I display error in localhost/ after user post one of the form ?

Currently the error will display in localhost/Account/LogOn or localhost/Account/SignUp

These are my codes:

```
#Index Action in HomeController

    Public Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return PartialView("_default")
    End Function

#_default layout
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            @code
                Html.RenderAction("SignUp", "Account")
            End Code

            @code
                 Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account")
            End Code
        </body>
    </html>

#SignUp Action in AccountController

Public Function SignUp() As ActionResult
    Return PartialView()
End Function

<HttpPost()> _
Public Function SignUp(user As UserView) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
         'some process
         Return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home")
    Else
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email already taken")
    End If

    Return PartialView(user)
End Function
```

Basically LogOn Action in AccountController same with SignUp Action

I think I'm stuck with the `Return PartialView(user)`

I need to return to Index Action in HomeController and maintain the ModelState

Any hint to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that usage of prg (POST-REDIRECT-GET) pattern is a good practice, and can help you in managing your problem. The modelState is imported and exported with filters.

Look at the point no 13 here
http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg

I think it's always relevant.